# Container lxc has two IP: One of them is bridge's. When connect with juju, connects to bridge's

Tags: juju, lxc, landscape, openstack-autopilot

If I install OpenStack with openstack-installer (autopilot) and the bootstrap for the first environment is launched over the VM that comes with openstack-installer pachage (openstack-installer/tools/vm-batch), landscape service will be installed on a container inside that VM (juju-machine-0-lxc-2 in my case). That container has two IPs (one for the bridge, lxcbr0, and the other one is the actual IP address I supposed to connect, eth0).
Whan I execute:

```
$ JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/ juju ssh landscape/0
```

from MAAS server, it connects to the VM, instead the container that has landscape.

In the VM, if I execute:
sudo lxc-ls -f
in every container appears:

```
NAME                      STATE    IPV4                      IPV6  AUTOSTART
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
juju-machine-0-lxc-1      RUNNING  10.222.221.139            -     YES
```

but in the landscape one appears this way:

```
NAME                      STATE    IPV4                      IPV6  AUTOSTART
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
juju-machine-0-lxc-2      RUNNING  10.0.3.1, 10.222.221.140  -     YES
```

(10.0.3.1 is the bridge IP).

So, basically, when I try to connect to the landscape container, it goes to 10.0.3.1, instead of 10.222.221.140.
My guess is that if I change IPs order that lxc sees, or just get rid of the bridge IP from lxc-ls, would solve the problem.
Any ideas?

UPDATE: If I execute:

```
JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/ juju status | grep -A 4 landscape/0 | grep public-address | awk '{print $2}'"
```

it gives me the IP 10.0.3.1, which is the lxcbr0 IP address, instead of the eth0 one. Maybe there is where I have to do some changes.

Regards,

Sacha.

Comment: It seems this is the problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1416928

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the comment with the [LP bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1416928), indeed that does seem to be the issue.  Updating to a fixed version of juju with:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:juju/stable
```

should fix this odd networking issue.